# Why this c program fall into infinity loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int sum=0;
  char s[10];

  while(scanf("%[^\n]s", s)!=EOF)
  {
    printf("%s", s);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

This while loop fall into infinity loop for any string input.

Comment: We should have some *beginners guide away from `scanf()`*. For starters, the `s` is wrong, because `[]` is already a conversion and `scanf()` would look for a literal `s` after it.

Comment: Then, when you fixed that, you'll have to deal with the newline character that's left after the first `scanf()`.

Comment: at 2nd time reject newline in `scanf("%[^\n]s", s)` After that the same.

Comment: For reading whole lines, just use `fgets()` and avoid all `scanf()`-trouble. (**including** buffer overflows -- they can be avoided with `scanf()` as well of course)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
while(scanf("%[^\n]s", s)!=EOF)
{
   printf("%s", s);
}
```

you ask *"Why this c program fall into infinity loop?"*

Therefore, you have to understand how `scanf()` works. `scanf()` uses your format string to parse input from `stdin`, which is a *stream that delivers character by character*.

Assume you have the following in `stdin`:

```
foo\n
bar\n
<<EOF>>
```

Now your format string has this conversion `%[^\n]` which means "match anything but newline and copy into a char buffer". The `s` following it is just a literal `s` because it doesn't have a `%` in front of it ... so it would match a literal `s` if there was one. In other words, it doesn't matter here.

Now, calling your `scanf()` the first time, it WILL match `foo` and consume it. it returns `1` because it matched one element. After that, `stdin` looks like this:

```
\n
bar\n
<<EOF>>
```

Note the unmatched newline **is still there**. Your next call again starts with a format string to match *anything but newline*, but the next character is a newline. `scanf()` matches nothing and therefore returns `0`. It cannot return `EOF` because, as you can see, `EOF` is not reached yet. Here is your infinite loop.

So, you have to fix your format string. First, remove the `s` that never matches anything. It doesn't really hurt here, but it's still wrong. Then, you can take advantage of the *whitespace matching* of `scanf()`. Whitespace is either *space*, *tab* or *newline*. If your format string contains whitespace, `scanf()` will match *as much whitespace as is there* (this can be none as well). Therefore, an easy fix would be to just start your format string with a space, this will "eat" the left-over newline:

```
while(scanf(" %[^\n]", s)!=EOF)
{
   printf("%s", s);
}
```

Now this is still **dangerous** code, because `[^\n]` matches any amount of characters as long as there is no newline, but your buffer has only room for 9 character plus terminating `0`. So you MUST tell `scanf()` not to match more than that limit, and this can be done by putting the number between the `%` and the conversion specification:

```
while(scanf(" %9[^\n]", s)!=EOF)
{
   printf("%s", s);
}
```

This code will do what you want in a safe manner, but assume you wanted to match something more specific, e.g. numbers, and you get some unexpected input: By waiting for `EOF`, you'd have your infinite loop again, because there is input that doesn't match, and so you can never reach `EOF` (as above with the unmatched newline). Therefore, always check for the number of successful matches instead. Here you expect exactly one match, so the loop should look like this:

```
while (scanf(" %9[^\n]", s) == 1)
{
   printf("%s", s);
}
```

---

In practice, for reading whole lines, you don't need `scanf()`, just using `fgets()` would be easier. Your code could look as simple as this (the newlines will be read into `s` as well):

```
while (fgets(s, 10, stdin))
{
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Note the second parameter `10` here: `fgets()` automatically accounts for the terminating `0` character, so you just give it the size of your buffer.

Just a final hint: this could be *even simpler* without using `printf()` when there's no formatting to do:

```
while (fgets(s, 10, stdin))
{
    fputs(s, stdout);
}
```

Comment: Best, as you say, is to use `fgets()`. Second best, using `scanf()` is to compare the return value against the number of expected assignments, not `EOF`: `while (scanf(" %9[^\n]", s) == 1) { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    char s[10];

    int ret = scanf("%[^\n]s", s);
    while (ret != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s", s);
        memset(s,0,10);
        ret = scanf("%[^\n]s", s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with the debug, you can see the second ret value in the while block is 0, that's , and not equal EOF, so infinity loop.

**man scanf:**

RETURN VALUE

Upon  successful  completion,  these  functions  shall  return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure.

That mean the other scanf is matching failure, except the first one.

But why?

The stdio has cache, and the matching only read "\n" from the stdin, but when you input the "Enter", it input "\n\r", so, the "\r" will in the stdin cache and become the input value for other scanf, but cannot match the input, so matching failure. And scanf return 0, and goto infinity loop.

But if you only input "\n" for each input, it's OK!

You can press "Alt" and at same time press "0" + "1" + "0", and the release the "Alt", the console will input "\n" only and you will get the right result , and the program will be OK, not into infinity loop!

And this's my test result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxduw.png)

Comment: And if you use "scanf("%[^\r\n]s", s);"  the scanf also can stop from the infinity loop, but you cannot input any more.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Note the `\n` is the newline character **in C** and when reading in text mode, any platform-specific newline is translated to just `\n`. Also note the windows newline is `\r\n`, not `\n\r`. And it goes on: `%[^\n]` doesn't match newline, it matches *anything **but** newline*

Comment: I am not sure now , I have try to use this scanf: "scanf("% [^\n]s", s);" (has s space at the beginning) and the result like the same with "scanf("%[^\r\n]s", s);" it's can stop the loop, but cannot input any more.

Comment: `"% [^\n]s"` --> `" %[^\n]"`

Comment: @Jimmy: Not my downvote, but trust me, your answer is wrong, please see mine for an explanation.